# Coodinator Layout With Fragments / Toolbar not in the same XML

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

Hello so I want to achieve this with the toolbar and I have seen many tutorials which explain how to do it with all the layout in one XML file.

[image]

However, I do not know how to solve this problem in the following use case

I have an XML file which defines my toolbar

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_top_padding"
    app:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Then I include this toolbar in an activity layout (linear layout root) which contains a frame layout as a container for a fragment

```
<include
android:id="@+id/app_bar"
layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          >
```

Now this fragment is inflated dynamically and the fragment is a recycler view. 
Can someone point me into how I link CoordinatorLayout with this common arrangement?

Thanks !

**EDIT Have solved this issue but let me know if there is a mistake**

My Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My Toolbar layout which has the scroll flags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be a problem as long as the `Toolbar` is added to a `CoordinatorLayout`, wrapped in an `AppBarLayout`. If you've tried it and still have problems, show the code you've tried and we can work through that.

Comment: Hello, I solved the issue and forgot about this question :) but i posted the code in case the way i did it is wrong. Could you check it over? Thanks!